# Object movement in a 2D Array/Grid

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a variation of the classic Snake game.

Basically what i am stuck on is how to restrict the snake movement to a 2D array whereby there will be a 20x20 grid.

At the moment, my snake head which is just a shape drawn with a midpoint, moves freely one pixel at a time within the game board. I require the snake to move one grid space at a time.

**This is my snake code:**

```
void Snake::move()
{
    switch(direction_){
    case Direction::North:
        position_.y += 1;
        break;
    case Direction::East:
        position_.x += 1;
        break;
    case Direction::South:
        position_.y -= 1;
        break;
    case Direction::West:
        position_.x -= 1;
    }

    if (position_.x < 6.4) position_.x = 44.8; else if (position_.x > 44.8) position_.x = 6.4;
    if (position_.y < 0) position_.y = 38.4; else if (position_.y > 38.4) position_.y = 0;

}

void Snake::render(prg::Canvas& canvas) const
{

    canvas.drawCircle(getPosition().x * 20, getPosition().y * 20,19.2,prg::Colour::GREEN);
}

void Snake::changeDirection(Direction new_direction)
{
    direction_ = new_direction;
}
```

**This is the code that handles keyboard input/movement**

```
PlayerSnake::PlayerSnake()
{
    prg::application.addKeyListener(*this);
}

PlayerSnake::~PlayerSnake()
{
    prg::application.removeKeyListener(*this);
}

bool PlayerSnake::onKey(const prg::IKeyEvent::KeyEvent& key_event)
{
    if(key_event.key_state == KeyEvent::KB_DOWN) {
        switch(key_event.key) {

        case KeyEvent::KB_LEFT_KEY:
            changeDirection(Direction::West);
            break;
        case KeyEvent::KB_RIGHT_KEY:
            changeDirection(Direction::East);
            break;
        case KeyEvent::KB_UP_KEY:
            changeDirection(Direction::North);
            break;
        case KeyEvent::KB_DOWN_KEY:
            changeDirection(Direction::South);
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I'm in desperate need of any suggestions and have been racking my brain trying to get the snake to move along a grid. I'm also new-ish to C++ so please understand.

Thanks :)

Comment: Don't store the coordinates as pixels, but grid spaces, and multiple the grid coordinates by the size of the cells when drawing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, how exactly would i go about doing this? is there any code i could add to the above to achieve this?

Comment: You could also keep storing the coordinates as pixels, but when drawing, divide, cut-off and then multiple by the cell size. So if the pixel x = 13 and grid is 8 pixels width. int(13 / 8) = 1.. * 8 = 8. So snaps to grid at 8.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of the screen as the data. The screen is a representation of the data. This means that you have to figure out a way to map the data to it's visual equivalent.

If the grid is 20x20, but the screen rendering is 200x200, this implies a 1:10 ratio of pixels to cells.  So, one possible method of drawing might look like this. (Sorry, using Processing syntax.)

In processing, one method of drawing a rectangle is using the command rect(int left, int top, int right, int bottom);

So, one implementation might look like this:

```
void draw_square(int cellx, int celly)
{
   rect(cellx*10, celly*10, cellx*10+10, celly*10+10);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jeremy, so if i want a 20x20 grid on a 768x768 game board, each grid square would represent 38.4x38.4 pixels?

How and where would i implement the code you mentioned?